# does the inverse of a rotation quaternion result in the inverse of its matrix form?

Tags: matrices, rotations, quaternions

according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), one can get the inverse of a rotation matrix by simply using its transpose. Does this extend to rotation quaternions?

Can I use the conjugate of a rotation quaternion, convert it to a matrix and get the inverses rotation matrix?

Comment: What is the transpose of a quaternion?

Comment: @amd Sorry, I meant to say conjugate, I've edited the question